# Tkinter threading

Tags: python, multithreading, tkinter

Despite seeing many questions being asked about this very topic, I can not find a suitable answer for my quandary. I am a beginner at Python and it is my first language. I am trying to create a dialog box that runs a test automatically on opening the box. When the test finishes, I want another dialog box to open which states the test is complete. The test is functional and runs properly. However, since the secondary dialog is calling a second instance of `Tk()`, it will not open.

My Question: How can I change my code in order to allow the secondary dialog box to open on completion of my test?

`obj_rcs` is the test being run.
`obj_config` is the secondary dialog box.

My Code:

```
enter code here
from configcomplete_slice import complete
from slice_setup import SLICE_SETUP
import Tkinter
import threading
import Queue

class GuiPart:

    def __init__(self, master, queue):
        self.queue = queue
        master.geometry("300x100+400+250")
        master.title("RSAM BCT")
        Tkinter.Label(master, text= "REDCOM SLICE", fg="red").pack()
        Tkinter.Label(master, text= "BCT - Basic Configuration Test",    
        fg= "red").pack()
        Tkinter.Label(master, text= "Please wait...", fg= "black").pack()
        Tkinter.Label(master, text= "Estimated time: 3 min 6 sec", 
        fg= "black").pack()


    def processIncoming(self):
        while self.queue.qsize():
            try:
                msg = self.queue.get(0)
                print msg
            except Queue.Empty:
                pass

class ThreadedClient:

    def __init__(self, master):
        self.master = master
        # Create the queue
        self.queue = Queue.Queue()
        # Set up the GUI part
        self.gui = GuiPart(master, self.queue)
        # Set up the thread to do asynchronous I/O
        self.running = 1
        self.thread1 = threading.Thread(target = self.workerThread1)
        self.thread1.start()
        self.periodicCall()

    def periodicCall(self):
        self.gui.processIncoming()
        if not self.running:
            import sys
            sys.exit(1)
        self.master.after(100, self.periodicCall)

    def workerThread1(self):
        while self.running:
            obj_rcs = SLICE_SETUP()
            obj_com = complete()

            obj_rcs.SLICE()
            obj_com.config()

root = Tkinter.Tk()
client = ThreadedClient(root)
root.mainloop()

class complete:

    def config(self):
        Tkinter.geometry("400x300+400+250")
        Tkinter.title("RSAM BCT")
        Tkinter.Label(master, text= "REDCOME SLICE", fg="red").pack()
        Tkinter.Label(master, text= "BCT - Basic Configuration Test", fg= "red").pack()
        Tkinter.Label(master, text= "Configuration Complete!", fg= "dark green").pack()
        Tkinter.Label(master, text= "Trunk 1: Port 1: Phone 1: 760-450-4500", 
        fg= "black").pack()
        Tkinter.Label(master, text= "Trunk 1: Port 2: Phone 2: 760-450-4501", 
        fg= "black").pack()
        Tkinter.Button(master, text = "    Exit    ", 
        command = Tkinter.destroy).pack()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like the problem is that you are creating another Tk element when you call the functions in the other modules, since you don't pass the one you create to the `complete()` function. Thus, it should accept a `master` argument, and then use it in the other module and then avoid multiple root Tk elements.

Besides, you are using more than one geometry manager (`place` and `pack`). You should use only one in the same window to avoid unexpected behaviour. Besides, this methods always return `None`, so the assignments like `plabel = ...` are useless - not only because it stores `None` but also because it may be misleading.

---

*EDIT:* I've added a modification of your code so you can have an overview of how to communicate with the spawn thread. I have not tested it, but at least it can be a reference to get the general idea.

```
from slice_setup import SLICE_SETUP
import Tkinter as tk
import threading
import Queue

class GuiPart:
    def __init__(self, master, queue):
        self.queue = queue
        self.master = master
        self.master.geometry("300x100+400+250")
        self.master.title("RSAM BCT")
        tk.Label(master, text="REDCOM SLICE", fg="red").pack()
        tk.Label(master, text="BCT - Basic Configuration Test", fg= "red").pack()
        tk.Label(master, text="Please wait...", fg= "black").pack()
        tk.Label(master, text="Estimated time: 3 min 6 sec", fg= "black").pack()

    def processIncoming(self):
        while self.queue.qsize():
            try:
                text = self.queue.get(0)
                Complete(self.master, text)
            except Queue.Empty:
                pass

class ThreadedClient:
    def __init__(self, master):
        self.master = master
        self.queue = Queue.Queue()
        self.gui = GuiPart(master, self.queue)
        self.running = True
        self.thread = threading.Thread(target=self.workerThread1)
        self.thread.start()
        self.periodicCall()

    def periodicCall(self):
        self.gui.processIncoming()
        if not self.running:
            return
        self.master.after(100, self.periodicCall)

    def workerThread1(self):
        obj_rcs = SLICE_SETUP()
        obj_rcs.SLICE()
        self.queue.put("Configuration Complete!")
        self.running = False

class Complete(tk.Toplevel):
    def __init__(self, master=None, completetext=""):
        tk.Toplevel.__init__(self, master)
        self.geometry("400x300+400+250")
        self.title("RSAM BCT")
        tk.Label(self, text="REDCOME SLICE", fg="red").pack()
        tk.Label(self, text="BCT - Basic Configuration Test", fg="red").pack()
        tk.Label(self, text=completetext, fg="dark green").pack()
        tk.Label(self, text="Trunk 1: Port 1: Phone 1: 760-450-4500", fg="black").pack()
        tk.Label(self, text="Trunk 1: Port 2: Phone 2: 760-450-4501", fg="black").pack()
        tk.Button(self, text="    Exit    ", command=self.destroy).pack()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = Tkinter.Tk()
    client = ThreadedClient(root)
    root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Be careful of your terminology. "Same window" is vague. What do you mean by "window"? A widget? A Toplevel window?  You shouldn't mix them in the same container widget, but mixing them in the same application is fine. Mixing them in the same window is fine if you are using "window" to mean the window as a whole, including all its child widgets. Mixing them is bad if you really mean the same instance of `Tk` or `Toplevel`.

Comment: @BryanOakley I used the word "window" because this terminology is also used in the documentation to refer to the root window and the Toplevel widget: http://www.pythonware.com/library/tkinter/introduction/application-windows.htm, http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/wm.htm

Comment: How do I create the master argument for my secondary dialog box?

Comment: @GeorgeLonngren It depends on how do you create the dialog: If it is a Toplevel widget, pass the master as the first argument of the constructor. If it is a call to a function of `tkMessageBox` you don't need it, but then the cause of your problem is something different.

Comment: @A. Rodas I have added the class I want to reference into my code. I already know it's not even functional right now as I was trying to switch out certain values in certain places. Forgive me for my lack of understanding, but unless I did it wrong, passing the master argument was not working for me.

Comment: @GeorgeLonngren See my edit, I've added a sample to make it clearer. Please let me know if you have any doubt.

Comment: @A.Rodas Your sample made everything clear to me. Thank you very much.